# How to load next draggable item only after the current item has been moved?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

I want multiple draggable items to "come out" of the same place. When the first one is dragged away, the second one loads and becomes available to drag. When the second one is dragged away, the third div will load, and so on.

Right now, Div 2 is already loaded and in a visible state regardless of where Div 1 is. When you move Div 1 away, you'll see the underlying Div 2. What I want is for Div 2 to be "hidden". It should only load and become visible when Div 1 is dragged away.

Thanks for your help.

What I've tried.

https://jsfiddle.net/0wg8sqmz/

```
<div id="drag1" class="drag" style="left:10px;top:20px;background-color:orange">Draggable 1</div>
<div id="drag2" class="drag" style="left:10px;top:-90px;background-color:lightblue">Draggable 2</div>
```

JS

```
$(function () {
    $(".drag").draggable({            
        stack: ".drag"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that quite easily by using data attributes.

See the below code.

Each DIV has a `data-index` attribute (for example `data-index="1"`) and when an element is dragged (drag has stopped), it will show the element with the next index `let next = $(this).data('index') + 1;`.

Every DIV except the first one is set to `display: none` to hide them in the first place.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".drag").draggable({
    stack: ".drag",
    stop: function() {
      
      // Calculate next index
      let next = $(this).data('index') + 1;
      
      // Show next DIV based on data-index
      $('div[data-index="' + next + '"]').show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.drag {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightpink;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- HTML -->
<div id="drag1" data-index="1" class="drag" style="left:10px;top:20px;background-color:orange">Draggable 1</div>

<div id="drag2" data-index="2" class="drag" style="left:10px;top:20px;background-color:lightblue; display: none;">Draggable 2</div>

<div id="drag3" data-index="3" class="drag" style="left:10px;top:20px;background-color:lightblue; display: none;">Draggable 3</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```